# Bypassing Capacitive Touch Sensor on Wemo Insight

Tags: sensor, identification, capacitive

I have a WeMo Insight plug that I'd like to use to monitor the power consumption of my networking devices but unfortunately if the power goes out, the WeMo device will not come back on automatically.  I can mechanically press the button to turn it on, but thought ideally I could control it with a little a microcontroller.  After doing [some research](https://www.edn.com/teardown-smart-plug-adds-energy-consumption-monitoring/) and [checking out](https://hackaday.io/project/6799-smartee-the-smart-plug) some [teardown articles](https://hackaday.io/project/5093-belkin-wemo-insight-teardown), I couldn't find anything definitive on how the capacitive touch sensor works.

I opened mine hoping to find out more but cannot figure out how the touch sensor works or what controls it (I understand it's the metal piece coming off the circuit board, but not what it connects to).  I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as to how it might be working so I can continue on with this project.

[image: Image of circuit board]

If this weren't the device controlling my networking equipment, I could easily toggle the device on/off via an API.  My back up is to just use a stylus and servo to mechanically trigger the touch sensor...though it wouldn't be as clean.

Edit: I've been testing continuity to narrow down how this works.  Apologies for the low quality MS Paint quality markings. The IC only has `127DIK` printed on it with pin 1 being at the bottom right.

[image: circuit board with continuity markings]

Comment: the picture above is very good ... the others are very poor

Comment: @jsotola yeah, I was having a hard time getting my phone to focus :(  Hopefully the new image I've added will be more helpful